# Align text within drop down list option elements

Tags: html, css

I have an html page with an option list where the user will choose to display information related to an event.  As such, I want each option in the drop down list to show a date and X happened to Y.  Within the option list, I'd like to have the dates left-aligned, then the "X's" aligned among the different options, then the "Y's" aligned with each other (I believe it will make it easier for people to see the differences when scanning the list).

Basically (as best as I can render here), this is what I'd like to do:

```
1/1/2000    This thing shipped           to Anywhere, KS
12/18/2003  The other thing installed    at Nowhere, NV
3/22/2007   The darned thing failed      in Roswell, NM
            ^ 2nd block aligned          ^ 3rd block aligned
```

I've tried div's within the option entries, but that made no difference.

I have searched exhaustively for something along these lines, but I haven't found anything even close (only questions on how to center align the entire option text, etc.).  Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

A select is not way to do this if you want formatting like that. HTML is not allowed in an option tag. According to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), permitted content of an option tag is:

> Text with eventually escaped characters (like é).

If you want to keep the "look" you'll need to find a different approach, like a table with a radio button in the first column of each row.

Comment: Thanks @bobdye for your response.  But I was hoping for at least a _couple_ more, though!  One alternative I thought of was to do it using a monospace font and manually adjusting the string lengths. I would just have to go through the result set at least twice (so I could determine which records had the longest strings in each column and adjust accordingly).

Comment: That might work, but you are likely to see variations between browsers that mean that it could look right in one browser in not others. Also, you would need to use non-breaking-spaces for your spaces to prevent browsers from collapsing them to 1 space. I don't know whether there is such a thing as a monospace non-breaking-space.

Comment: Yup.  Another effect is that the monospace font would be inconsistent with the other fonts used elsewhere on the page.